# Remember the first string from an object when using recursion

Tags: php, recursion

This is a very simplified version of the function I am having issues with:

```
function example(&$form) {
     $name = $form->getName();

     foreach ($form as $sub) {
          if ($sub instanceof Form) {
               example($sub);
          }
          // need this to be the first entry of $name
          echo $name;
      }

 }

 example($this->form);
```

I need a way to keep the value of the first entry of `$name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding another param to the function

```
function example(&$form, $firstFormName = null) {
    $name = $form->getName();

    if(is_null($firstFormName))
        $firstFormName = $name;

    foreach ($form as $sub) {
        if ($sub instanceof Form) {
           example($sub, $firstFormName);
        }
    }
    // need this to be the first entry of $name
    echo $name;
}

example($this->form);
```

Comment: Except that I need `$name` to generate everytime as well. So I need a copy of the FIRST $name, and also each individual as well.

Comment: this is a good solution, or if you dont want it to be null, you can count the iterations of the function and only set it on the first iteration.  `i==1` type thing.  just read your comment.  in that case, assign it to another name on the first iteration.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a new variable called `$firstFormName`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the value along as a parameter

```
function example(&$form, $init_name = null) {
    $name = $form->getName();
    if (empty($init_name)) {
        $init_name = $name;
    }

     foreach ($form as $sub) {
          if ($sub instanceof Form) {
               example($sub, $init_name);
          }
          // current name
          echo $name;
          // initial name
          echo $init_name;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do the trick for you.

```
$first_name = "";
foreach ($form as $sub) {
   if ($first_name == "") {
      $first_name = $sub;
   }
// The rest of your for loop here...
```